# Copy UIView in Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, storyboard, xcode6

Coping a `UIView` from a `UIViewController` to another as following:

1. Select the view.
2. Copy (cmd + c).
3. Select the view to place inside in the other `UIViewController`.
4. Paste (cmd + v).

This will not put the copied view inside the selected one. It will replace it.

I want to place it inside. How to do that?

Comment: put one dummy view in the view cycle then do your change on that ....

Comment: problem solved or still u have faced the same

Comment: @Spynet: How did you chose the view (Step 3)

Comment: @MidhunMP 5k scored user knows how to do this , i think hasan83 did that one ok there is no more step 3 or 4 problem is solved that's it!

Comment: @Spynet you first comment solves the problem. please, add it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Spynet There is nothing with reputation or 5K. In new concepts everyone is a baby. :)

Comment: @MidhunMP your right but u just went though its profile u know how much knowledge he has when compared to him i am as a baby .... Cool:) keep posting comment that will improve our learning and mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put one dummy view in the view cycle then do your change on that ....

Comment: can you please edit your answer. I know what you mean but I because you did a comment before. But, from my point of view. it's un-understandable ;)

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any problem with what you are trying to do unless you using ctrl instead of command; copy : command + C

OR 
 Try drag and drop the view from one ViewController to other

Comment: my mistake. actually I do command not control. question is wrong I update.